# Spring JPA update query using @Modifying annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using the below query to update a record in the databse

```
@Query("update ObjectActionCommon o set o.receiptGenerated ='Yes' where o.id in (:objectId)")
@Modifying
void setGenerateReceiptfield(@Param("objectId") Long objectId);
```

But Hibernate fires the below query and appends 'HT' to the table name gives View does not exist exception

```
INSERT INTO HT_CHAIN_OF_CUSTODY_LOG
SELECT objectacti0_.ID AS ID
FROM CHAIN_OF_CUSTODY_LOG objectacti0_
WHERE objectacti0_.ID=?;
```

'CHAIN_OF_CUSTODY_LOG' is the actual table name in the db.

I dont know what am I doing wrong!

Comment: http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/

Comment: Please post the  ObjectActionCommon entity code.